# What are some good resources for tablet drawing?

Tags: tutorial, resource-recommendations, drawing-tablet

What are some good resources for tablet drawing? Doesn't matter what media ... books, articles, video tutorials, anything else.

Comment: For drawing what?

Comment: This is wayyy too broad. Needs much more detail IMO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean getting used to drawing on a tablet in general, then there is nothing better than experience. You will learn more  by using it than you ever will by reading about it. That said, there are some tips for getting to know the Wacom tablets here: http://www.hypergurl.com/blog/webdesigntools/drawing-tablet.html

Comment: The videos at that link are down.  :-(

Answer (score 3):

To be honest, I learnt drawing and sketching on paper first before jumping into tablet drawing. Once when I started to paint with acrylics on a real canvas I could do some magical things in Photoshop.

I use Wacom Intuous 2 and the Wacom Bamboo, but I also have a sketch pad that I bring along with me to capture ideas to draw. There are some skills that transfer from paper to a computer tablet quite easily. Getting used to the tablet depends solely on your eye-hand coordination, or willingness to train.